# Improving on the data processing inequality for Markov chains

Tags: markov-chains, information-theory, entropy

Given a Markov chain $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$, the data processing inequality bounds the mutual information

$$I(X;Z) \leq \min \big( I(X;Y),I(Y;Z) \big)$$

However, it seems intuitive that we should be able to do better through some combination of these quantities. For example, if $X$ is a uniform binary random variable, $Y$ flips $X$ with probability $1/4$, and $Z$ flips $Y$ with probability $1/4$, then $I(X;Z)$ should be strictly lower than either $I(X;Y)$ or $I(Y;Z)$, right? More broadly, if I have a Markov chain of successive corrupting channels

$$X_1 \rightarrow X_2 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow X_k$$

I would imagine that $I(X_1;X_k)$ is much lower than any one $I(X_j;X_{j+1})$. However, I'm not aware of any such result, nor am I clear on why such a result does not exist. Can someone either provide a similar result or explain why one does not exist?

Comment: What do you mean by doing "better"? What does it mean for $Y$ to "flip" $X$? Are the random variables you've specified a Markov chain?

Comment: By doing "better" I mean that, in the example I sketched, it seems like $I(X;Z) < \min(I(X;Y),I(Y;Z))$, so the inequality $I(X;Z) \leq \min(I(X;Y),I(Y;Z))$ is not tight. By "$Y$ flip[ping] $X$" I mean that $Y$ is is a function $f(X)$ that with probability $3/4$ outputs $X$ and with probability $1/4$ outputs its negation (so 0 becomes 1 and vice versa). It is a Markov chain as $X$ and $Z$ are conditionally independent given $Y$, no?

Comment: equality in the data processing inequality may hold but only when a certain condition holds (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_processing_inequality)). When this is not the case, the inequality is strict.

Comment: Right, so I'm wondering if it's possible to show a stronger inequality in that case. More broadly, for a Markov chain $X_1 \rightarrow X_2 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow X_k$ the best upper bound I know of for $I(X_1;X_k)$ is $I(X_1;X_k) \leq \min(I(X_1;X_2), I(X_2;X_3), \ldots, I(X_{k-1};X_k))$. But it seems like something more akin to $I(X_1;X_k) \leq \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} I(X_i;X_{i+1})$ should hold -- not literally this relationship, but something that takes advantage of this kind of "composition".

Comment: This is an active area of research, and is, AFAIK, far from settled in general. Google for the 'strong data processing inequality'. For the particular question you asked with the long Markov chain, Polyansky and Wu have a recent paper that might be of interest.

Comment: @stochasticboy321, "strong data processing inequality" was useful, and seems to be about as good as I can hope for here. Thanks! Can you make it an answer so I can accept?